# Read matrix from file which has column and row name

Tags: numpy, matrix, file-io

I need to load a matrix from a text file. But the tricky thing about this matrix is it has column and row name in like this

```
        A  R  N  D  C  Q  E  G  H  I  L  K  M  F  P  S  T  W  Y  V
      A  4 -1 -2 -2  0 -1 -1  0 -2 -1 -1 -1 -1 -2 -1  1  0 -3 -2  0
      R -1  5  0 -2 -3  1  0 -2  0 -3 -2  2 -1 -3 -2 -1 -1 -3 -2 -3
      N -2  0  6  1 -3  0  0  0  1 -3 -3  0 -2 -3 -2  1  0 -4 -2 -3
      D -2 -2  1  6 -3  0  2 -1 -1 -3 -4 -1 -3 -3 -1  0 -1 -4 -3 -3
      C  0 -3 -3 -3  9 -3 -4 -3 -3 -1 -1 -3 -1 -2 -3 -1 -1 -2 -2 -1
      Q -1  1  0  0 -3  5  2 -2  0 -3 -2  1  0 -3 -1  0 -1 -2 -1 -2
      E -1  0  0  2 -4  2  5 -2  0 -3 -3  1 -2 -3 -1  0 -1 -3 -2 -2
      G  0 -2  0 -1 -3 -2 -2  6 -2 -4 -4 -2 -3 -3 -2  0 -2 -2 -3 -3
      H -2  0  1 -1 -3  0  0 -2  8 -3 -3 -1 -2 -1 -2 -1 -2 -2  2 -3
      I -1 -3 -3 -3 -1 -3 -3 -4 -3  4  2 -3  1  0 -3 -2 -1 -3 -1  3
      L -1 -2 -3 -4 -1 -2 -3 -4 -3  2  4 -2  2  0 -3 -2 -1 -2 -1  1
      K -1  2  0 -1 -3  1  1 -2 -1 -3 -2  5 -1 -3 -1  0 -1 -3 -2 -2
      M -1 -1 -2 -3 -1  0 -2 -3 -2  1  2 -1  5  0 -2 -1 -1 -1 -1  1
      F -2 -3 -3 -3 -2 -3 -3 -3 -1  0  0 -3  0  6 -4 -2 -2  1  3 -1
      P -1 -2 -2 -1 -3 -1 -1 -2 -2 -3 -3 -1 -2 -4  7 -1 -1 -4 -3 -2
      S  1 -1  1  0 -1  0  0  0 -1 -2 -2  0 -1 -2 -1  4  1 -3 -2 -2
      T  0 -1  0 -1 -1 -1 -1 -2 -2 -1 -1 -1 -1 -2 -1  1  5 -2 -2  0
      W -3 -3 -4 -4 -2 -2 -3 -2 -2 -3 -2 -3 -1  1 -4 -3 -2 11  2 -3
      Y -2 -2 -2 -3 -2 -1 -2 -3  2 -1 -1 -2 -1  3 -3 -2 -2  2  7 -1
      V  0 -3 -3 -3 -1 -2 -2 -3 -3  3  1 -2  1 -1 -2 -2  0 -3 -1  4
```

I want to take off all the alphabet and want to have a matrix only with numbers separated by a comma.
What is the best way to do that? Is there any useful function for this?

Comment: Maybe you ignore the 1st row and then from second row onwards, ignore the first element

Answer (score 0):

With `pandas` and your `filename` of the file instead of `matrix.txt`

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv('matrix.txt', sep='\s+').values
```

Out:

```
array([[ 4, -1, -2, -2,  0, -1, -1,  0, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -2, -1,  1,  0, -3, -2,  0],
       [-1,  5,  0, -2, -3,  1,  0, -2,  0, -3, -2,  2, -1, -3, -2, -1, -1, -3, -2, -3],
       [-2,  0,  6,  1, -3,  0,  0,  0,  1, -3, -3,  0, -2, -3, -2,  1,  0, -4, -2, -3],
       [-2, -2,  1,  6, -3,  0,  2, -1, -1, -3, -4, -1, -3, -3, -1,  0, -1, -4, -3, -3],
       [ 0, -3, -3, -3,  9, -3, -4, -3, -3, -1, -1, -3, -1, -2, -3, -1, -1, -2, -2, -1],
       [-1,  1,  0,  0, -3,  5,  2, -2,  0, -3, -2,  1,  0, -3, -1,  0, -1, -2, -1, -2],
       [-1,  0,  0,  2, -4,  2,  5, -2,  0, -3, -3,  1, -2, -3, -1,  0, -1, -3, -2, -2],
       [ 0, -2,  0, -1, -3, -2, -2,  6, -2, -4, -4, -2, -3, -3, -2,  0, -2, -2, -3, -3],
       [-2,  0,  1, -1, -3,  0,  0, -2,  8, -3, -3, -1, -2, -1, -2, -1, -2, -2,  2, -3],
       [-1, -3, -3, -3, -1, -3, -3, -4, -3,  4,  2, -3,  1,  0, -3, -2, -1, -3, -1,  3],
       [-1, -2, -3, -4, -1, -2, -3, -4, -3,  2,  4, -2,  2,  0, -3, -2, -1, -2, -1,  1],
       [-1,  2,  0, -1, -3,  1,  1, -2, -1, -3, -2,  5, -1, -3, -1,  0, -1, -3, -2, -2],
       [-1, -1, -2, -3, -1,  0, -2, -3, -2,  1,  2, -1,  5,  0, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1,  1],
       [-2, -3, -3, -3, -2, -3, -3, -3, -1,  0,  0, -3,  0,  6, -4, -2, -2,  1,  3, -1],
       [-1, -2, -2, -1, -3, -1, -1, -2, -2, -3, -3, -1, -2, -4,  7, -1, -1, -4, -3, -2],
       [ 1, -1,  1,  0, -1,  0,  0,  0, -1, -2, -2,  0, -1, -2, -1,  4,  1, -3, -2, -2],
       [ 0, -1,  0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -2, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -2, -1,  1,  5, -2, -2,  0],
       [-3, -3, -4, -4, -2, -2, -3, -2, -2, -3, -2, -3, -1,  1, -4, -3, -2, 11,  2, -3],
       [-2, -2, -2, -3, -2, -1, -2, -3,  2, -1, -1, -2, -1,  3, -3, -2, -2,  2,  7, -1],
       [ 0, -3, -3, -3, -1, -2, -2, -3, -3,  3,  1, -2,  1, -1, -2, -2,  0, -3, -1,  4]])
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!